# How can I convert from scatter size to data coordinates in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to programmatically test whether two scatterplot glyphs will overlap in matplotlib. So given a pair of (x, y) coordinates and a size (which as i understand is the area of the circle, in points), I would like to plot

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=s)
```

and then have a function called `points_overlap` that takes these parameters and returns `True` if the points will overlap and `False` otherwise.

```
def points_overlap(x, y, s):
    if ...
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I know there are transformation matrices to take me between the different [matplotlib coordinate systems](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html), but I can't figure out the right steps for writing this function.

Comment: just a shot in the dark, but it seems possible that the responsible parties behind `beeswarm` know a thing or two about this. (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb)

Comment: As far as I could tell from the pybeeswarm code, the size and offset of the scatter points is a parameter to the function and requires some trial-and-error to get things aligned. Hence this question :)

Comment: Dang -- I was hoping they had it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

This needs some testing, but it might work? These should all be in Display space

```
def overlap(x, y, sx, sy):
    return np.linalg.norm(x - y) < np.linalg.norm(sx + sy)
```

test:

```
In [227]: X = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [2.5, 1]])
In [228]: s = np.array([20, 10000, 10000])

In [229]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

In [230]: ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=s)
Out[230]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x10c32f28>

In [231]: plt.draw()
```

Test every pair:

```
Xt = ax.transData.transform(X)
st = np.sqrt(s)

pairs = product(Xt, Xt)
sizes = product(st, st)

for i, ((x, y), (sx, sy)) in enumerate(zip(pairs, sizes)):
    h = i % 3
    j = i // 3
    if h != j and overlap(x, y, sx, sy):
        print((i, h, j))
```

[image]

There's lots of room for improvement. It's probably easier to transform all your data and pass that into the `points_overlap` function instead of doing the transform inside. That'd be much better actually.

Comment: This seems close but not quite there. See [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/mwaskom/000cb7d78e8ea6ac286b) notebook for some more tests.